# Mysql workbench tcp/ip over ssh vagrant

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant

Pessoal estou tentando criar um ambiente java no vagrant, instalei o mysql e nao estou conseguindo me conectar ao mysql da minha vm pelo meu workbench no host. Essa chave que estou usando é exatamente a mesma que uso no putty via ssh e da certo. Tambem usei esse usuario e senha do mysql na vm e da certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem poderia me ajudar? Obrigado Desde ja!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, consegui resolver meu problema a resolução foi sem noção pq assim a chave que eu estava usando no workbench é a mesma do meu PuTTy que uso pra me conectar via SSH sem pedir senha, daí eu retirei a chave do meu workbench e usei a senha da VM e deu certo . Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Essa foi sua solução, porém não é a mais adequada para esse problema. Isso acontece, pois as versões superiores ao 6.3 do mysql workbench não aceitam a extensão **.ppk** da chave ssh.

No meu caso, tive problemas com a versão 8.0 do workbench.

A solução mais adequada para esse problema, é realizar a conversão da chave ssh com a extensão .ppk, para o formato OpenSSH.

Para isso, abra o PuTTYgen > Conversions > Import Key > 'Selecione sua chave .ppk' > Export OpenSSH > Selecione o seu diretório e salve.

Use esse arquivo ssh, e realize o teste na conexão novamente que irá funcionar.

Vale lembrar que isso só é possível, se a chave ssh, estiver incluída no arquivo "autorized_keys" do servidor remoto.

Referência:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ssh-tunneling.html

Comment: Veja a data da pergunta e da resposta. Quando assim deixe claro em sua resposta que é uma atualização de conhecimento e não uma desqualificação de outra ou outras respostas.